# How can I break down this long string returned by the openweathermap API?

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

### Hey everyone!

So, recently I wanted to learn how to use an API and I figured the *openweathermap* API could be really fun. I successfully got the API request returning a value, but in its' current state it's unusable. Does anyone know how I can split this string appart to set each value here as a variable?

#### Here's the call I am using:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={not a real city}&appid={censored}', true); //not a real id
request.onload = function() {
    console.log(request.response);
}
request.send();
```

#### And the response I need to try and use looks something like:

```js
{"coord":{"lon":-85.4898,"lat":42.9595},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":267.51,"feels_like":262.69,"temp_min":265.93,"temp_max":269.26,"pressure":1026,"humidity":74},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":270},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1615029875,"sys":{"type":1,"id":4269,"country":"US","sunrise":1615032556,"sunset":1615073839},"timezone":-18000,"id":4993125,"name":"Forest Hills","cod":200}
```

So yea, that ^^ is what I need to try to break-down. I could use `string.split()` a bunch of times, but that seems really messy to me. I feel like there has to be a better way that I don't know about. I know this is probably really easy but, again, this is my first time using any API. I also tried searching the internet (and here on Stack) for an answer but couldn't find one.

Thanks!

Comment: Parse the JSON using `JSON.parse()`, then you'll have an object that you can either access properties of or iterate over to set your variables. [See MDN on JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for details.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I have not worked with JSON before so this reference will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JoshG mentionned, you can use [JSON.parse(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse any JSON-string into a javascript object.

An alternative would be to replace your current use of the older [XMLHttpRequest api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (which has a kind of messy API) with the newer [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (which is easier).

For example:

```js
fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={not a real city}&appid={censored}')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
```